# C Macro expansion not working as expected -- getting below error main.c:11:19: error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token

Tags: c, macros

I am trying to make a MACRO expansion which will expand to

if X = 0 , to "CLG_DATA"

IF X = 1 , to "CLG_DATA1"

IF X = 2, to "CLG_DATA2"

Basically for 0 , it should not give me CLG_DATA0. Instead I want CLG_DATA , for rest we can append the number.

Below MACRO Expansion in the code seems to give me an error

> main.c:11:19: error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define clgdet(x) ((x>0)?(clg_data):(clg_data ## x))

struct student_college_detail
{
    int college_id;
    char college_name[50];
}abc, *pabc, abc1, *pabc1;
 
struct student_detail 
{
    int id;
    char name[20];
    float percentage;
    // structure within structure
    struct student_college_detail *clg_data;
    struct student_college_detail *clg_data1;
    struct student_college_detail *clg_data2;
}stu_data, *stu_data_ptr;
 
int main() 
{
    struct student_college_detail abc = {71145 , "aa"};
    pabc = &abc;
    struct student_college_detail abc1 = {89145 , "bb"};
    pabc1 = &abc1;
  struct student_detail stu_data = {1, "Raj", 90.5 };
    stu_data_ptr = &stu_data;
    stu_data_ptr->clg_data = pabc;
    stu_data_ptr->clg_data1 = pabc1;
 
    printf(" Id is: %d \n", stu_data_ptr->id);
    printf(" Name is: %s \n", stu_data_ptr->name);
    printf(" Percentage is: %f \n\n", 
                         stu_data_ptr->percentage);
 
    printf(" College Id is: %d \n", 
                         stu_data_ptr->clgdet(0)->college_id);
    printf(" College Name is: %s \n", 
                      stu_data_ptr->clg_data1->college_name);
 
    return 0;
}
```

Why is this MACRO expansion not working ??
Also any other suggestion you guys have ?

Comment: The ternary operator is not evaluated when preprocessing, it's included in the expansion.

Comment: But wouldn't it be simpler to use an array? `struct student_college_detail *clg_data[3];`

Comment: Or just name the first member `clg_data0` instead of `clg_data`.

Comment: Why are you even using a macro here?  It is pointless -- just use `clg_data` instead of `clgdet(0)`

Answer (score 1):

You're expanding the macro where a member is expected:

```
stu_data_ptr->clgdet(0)->college_id
```

this expands to

```
stu_data_ptr->((0>0)?(clg_data):(clg_data0))->college_id
```

which  makes no sense. The right hand side of a `->` or `.` in C is an identifier, which names a member of the structure type implicated on the left hand side. This right hand side is not an expression; it cannot be calculated.

To choose one of two members, you have to pull in the entire `->` operator expression into the conditional.

```
(condition) ? stu_data_ptr->this_member : stu_data_ptr->that_member
```

Then that whole expression can be subject to more `->` chasing, assuming the members have compatible type:

```
((condition) ? stu_data_ptr->this_member : stu_data_ptr->that_member)->next_thing
```

It's not enough for both `this_member` and `that_member` to have a member called `next_thing`; they have to be of the same type. The overall `?:` expression has a type, and that type has to be a pointer to a struct/union which has a `next_thing` member.

This can be worked into the macro, like this. I'm also going to try to fix the condition to what seems to be what is wanted:

```
#define clgdet(ptr, x) ((x==0)?(ptr->clg_data):(ptr->clg_data ## x))
```

We call it like this now:

```
cldget(stu_data_ptr, 0)->college_id
```

The branch of the `?:` which is not taken is dead code, which the compiler will hopefully eliminate. However, the dead code has to type check. **So that is to say, if we use `0`, the live code wants to access a `clg_data` member, but the dead code refers to a member `clg_data0`, which must exist for it to compile.**

If it is not acceptable to introduce a dummy `clg_data0` member alongside `clg_data`, you can use some preprocessor trick to make the `0` disappear. The simplest one is this hack:

```
#define clg_data0 clg_data
```

In the case when `x` is zero, the macro then produces an expansion with `clg_data` in both sides of the conditional, thanks to this rewrite.

**Remark:** would avoid this sort of thing entirely and use an array:

```
struct student_detail 
{
    int id;
    char name[20];
    float percentage;
    // structure within structure
    struct student_college_detail *clg_data[3];
}
```

Now we have:

```
stu_data_ptr->clg_data[1]->college_id
```

instead of ugly preproessor hacks with `##` token pasting.

If you have the code under your control (you're building it yourself and are free to make changes), you can introduce the array without having to change many lines of code, like this:

```
struct student_detail 
{
    int id;
    char name[20];
    float percentage;
    // structure within structure
    struct student_college_detail *clg_dat[3];
}

#define clg_data clg_dat[0]
#define clg_data1 clg_dat[1]
#define clg_data2 clg_dat[3]
```

Thus code like `stuptr->clg_data1->college_id` continues to compile and work; it just translates to `stuptr->clg_dat[1]->college_id`.

Thus you can have the array now, and gradually phase out the legacy member names. Stick to that plan, and get those macros removed. Never leave things "half phased out"; mixtures of code with superimposed old and new conventions are the worst, especially if that is compounded over multiple generations of half-done improvements.

Comment: Thank you. `#define clg_data0 clg_data` seems to work. 
 Internet is super cool because of you guys :)

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using an array instead of treating individual member variables as a *de facto* array with preprocessor kludges. I would not approve code like this in production, without an extraordinarily convincing reason (such as code having to be fixed in hundreds of places to make it work) and even then, I would ask to put in a plan to actually do that and get rid of the hack.

Answer (score 1):

Macros do direct token substitution.  So this:

```
stu_data_ptr->clgdet(0)->college_id);
```

Expands to:

```
stu_data_ptr->((0>0)?(clg_data):(clg_data0))->college_id);
```

Which is invalid syntax because the right-hand side of the `->` operator must be a field name.

Another way to do what you want is to create an array instead of 3 separate fields:

```
struct student_detail 
{
    int id;
    char name[20];
    float percentage;
    // structure within structure
    struct student_college_detail *clg_data[3];
}stu_data, *stu_data_ptr;
```

Then you can do this:

```
stu_data_ptr->clg_data[0]->college_id);
```

Comment: No so I cannot really change the '"clg_data". I need to make some changes in a huge  code file which already has clg_data. And new members are named as clg_data1 , clg_data2.

BTW "#define clgdet(x) clg_data ## x"    is working fine , but I am getting clg_data0 instead of clg_data. So that's the issue

Comment: BTW   `stu_data_ptr->clg_data->college_id);` would have worked.
Shouldn't **clg_data** and **clg_data[0]** point to the same memory , like in the case of Simple Arrays , A[0] and A points to the starting address. 

But this approach is giving me segmentation fault

Comment: @HarshAgarwal Can you do a global find/replace `clg_data` -> `clg_data0`?

Comment: this particular member is used at many other places. It's not about a simple change, but then I have to take care of it's dependencies across many other files and projects